# Onclick button to pause and run CSS animation with nested nth-child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a working `css` animation. I meant it to loop through each child changing the background color with `keyframes`.

I'm attempting to create a button to pause and run the animation on click. What I have so far works only for the parent. I can only run and pause the parent. I can't make it work for the nested nth-child.

I've tried `document.querySelector('.animation1 animation1:nth-child(16n +1) animation1:nth-child(16n + 2))'`, `document.querySelectorAll()` but to no avail.

I've also attempted `document.getElementsByClassName('animation1').classList.add("animation-run");`.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button-ani');
 var test_ani = document.getElementsByClassName('animation1');

button.onclick = function() {
test_ani[0].classList.toggle('playani');
}


/*document.getElementsByClassName('animation1').classList.add("animation-run"); */
```

```css
.animation1 {
        --animation-delay: 0.1s;
        animation: ani_keyframes 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay) paused;
    }

/* animation-run

.animation-run {
        --animation-delay: 0.1s;
        animation: ani_keyframes 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay);
    }
    
*/
 
/* Without Paused
 
 .animation1 {
        --animation-delay: 0.1s;
        animation: ani_keyframes 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay);
    }
 
 */
    .playani {
        animation-play-state: running;
    }
    
    .animation1:hover {
        animation: none;
        fill: #666;
    }



.animation1:nth-child(16n + 1) {
    --animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.animation1:nth-child(16n + 2) {
    --animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.animation1:nth-child(16n + 3) {
    --animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.animation1:nth-child(16n + 4) {
    --animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.animation1:nth-child(16n + 5) {
    --animation-delay: 0.5s;
}


@keyframes ani_keyframes {
 0% {
        fill: #000;
    }
    40% {
        fill: #FF0;
    }
    80% {
        fill: #330;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="animation1_wrapper">
<button id="button-ani">Toggle Animation Play State</button>
<svg id="animation1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 418 255" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
    <g id="ani_graphic">
<path class="animation1" d="M263.46 25.3801C257.63 29.2001 252.88 33.7801 249.33 37.8001H263.46V25.3801Z" fill="#000"></path>
<path class="animation1" d="M301.26 37.8001V18.8701C300.92 18.7801 300.58 18.6801 300.24 18.6001C287.1 15.3201 275.8 18.2901 266.73 23.3901V37.8001H301.26Z" fill="#f1f1f1"></path>
<path class="animation1" d="M329.15 37.8001C324.38 30.2101 316.5 23.6801 304.54 19.8201V37.8001H329.15Z" fill="#f1f1f1"></path>
----
----
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to do animation on all the `classes` when you click play OR when you `click` it again the `animation` will stop on all `svg` elements

`querySelectorAll` method return a node list of same class found in the DOM tree and using `forEach` we can iterate through it all and apply `toggle` class on found element with that class name

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button-ani');
var test_ani = document.querySelectorAll('.animation1');

button.onclick = function() {
  test_ani.forEach(function(ani) {
    ani.classList.toggle('playani');
  })
}
```

```css
.animation1 {
  --animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation: ani_keyframes 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay) paused;
}


/* animation-run

.animation-run {
        --animation-delay: 0.1s;
        animation: ani_keyframes 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay);
    }
    
*/

/* Without Paused
 
 .animation1 {
        --animation-delay: 0.1s;
        animation: ani_keyframes 1.8s linear infinite var(--animation-delay);
    }
 
 */

.playani {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.animation1:hover {
  animation: none;
  fill: #666;
}

.animation1:nth-child(16n + 1) {
  --animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.animation1:nth-child(16n + 2) {
  --animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.animation1:nth-child(16n + 3) {
  --animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.animation1:nth-child(16n + 4) {
  --animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.animation1:nth-child(16n + 5) {
  --animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes ani_keyframes {
  0% {
    fill: #000;
  }
  40% {
    fill: #FF0;
  }
  80% {
    fill: #330;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animation1_wrapper">
  <button id="button-ani">Toggle Animation Play State</button>
  <svg id="animation1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 418 255" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <g id="ani_graphic">
      <path class="animation1" d="M263.46 25.3801C257.63 29.2001 252.88 33.7801 249.33 37.8001H263.46V25.3801Z" fill="#000"></path>
      <path class="animation1" d="M301.26 37.8001V18.8701C300.92 18.7801 300.58 18.6801 300.24 18.6001C287.1 15.3201 275.8 18.2901 266.73 23.3901V37.8001H301.26Z" fill="#f1f1f1"></path>
      <path class="animation1" d="M329.15 37.8001C324.38 30.2101 316.5 23.6801 304.54 19.8201V37.8001H329.15Z" fill="#f1f1f1"></path>
      ----
      ----
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```